# Return parent and his childrens from column and row

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parent-child

I have two functions that return column children and row children, how can I return the parents and their children’s separately, I mean each parent with his childrens.

```
function cols() {
    var c = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
            c[j].children[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
            alert(c[j].children[i] / 3 );
        }
    }
}
cols();

function rows() {
    var c = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.row'));
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
            c[i].children[j].style.borderColor = "red";
            alert(c[i].children[j]);
        }
    }
}
rows();
```

**[fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/truvh94a/8/)**

Comment: parent=child.parentElement

Comment: c.length loop in a c.length loop isnt a good idea isnt it?

Comment: @Jonas w not really :|

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
window.onload=function(){   
 rows=document.getElementsByClassName("row");
rows.forEach(function(row){
  colums=row.children;
colums.forEach(function(col){
alert(col,row);
});
});
}
```

Comment: unfortunatley is not really working :|  error "rows.forEach is not a function"  and I don't have a className "col" :| Anyway, try to put that in the fiddle.

Comment: @RulerNature: oh sorry, i think it can be solved with an onload handler

Comment: nope, because I don't have ".col" class, try it yourself in that fiddle that I added on question.

Comment: @RulersNature : hey, wheres the problem? Simply replace it with children

Comment: It is not working, check the fiddle :)    https://jsfiddle.net/truvh94a/10/

Comment: @RulerNature: i had a typo (".row")  but i still cant get this to work. Thats crazy